# How to access the Forms Authentication Ticket in Authenticated pages

Tags: asp.net

I have used the Forms Authentication for logging in and in that i have created the Forms Authentication Ticket and in that ticket i have passing the data with comma seperated values.
how can i get the data which is in the ticket to access in the Authenticated user pages

How can i do this?

Thanks & Regards,
Vara Prasad.M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]` will give you the Forms Authentication cookie.

`FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);` will take that cookie and turn it into the FormsAuthenticationTicket.

From there you can access [all sorts of properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket_members.aspx). It sounds like you'll want [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.name.aspx) and/or [UserData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.userdata.aspx).

You can follow this process from any place you can get an HttpRequest instance... which is pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Yeah this is working now 
thanks for ur solution 
so if i authenticated in one browser and copy the url in another browser it is getting an error
so for this what i have to do?

Comment: This is based on browser cookies, which aren't transferable via the URL. If you require the ability to pass information via the URL, you should ask it as a separate question, since it's an entirely different issue.